# Insert Into Code throws an error

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am using this code to insert 4 textboxes of data into a table.

```
CurrentDb.Execute = "INSERT INTO tbl_machineheader(Line No, Description, Service Interval, Type) values ( '" & Me.Combo3 & "', '" & Me.Text1 & "', '" & Me.Text6 & "', '" & Me.Text12 & "')"
```

However it doesn't seem to work and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

That "=" character is wrong:

```
CurrentDb.Execute **=** "INSERT INTO tbl_machineheader(Line No, Description, Service Interval, Type) values ( '" & Me.Combo3 & "', '" & Me.Text1 & "', '" & Me.Text6 & "', '" & Me.Text12 & "')"
```

Also you should use square brackets for your column names. The correct syntax is as follows:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tbl_machineheader([Line No], [Description], [Service Interval], [Type]) values ( '" & Me.Combo3 & "', '" & Me.Text1 & "', '" & Me.Text6 & "', '" & Me.Text12 & "')"
```

Comment: Your observations are correct, but an even better answer would have been to suggest avoiding SQL Injection vulnerabilities and other nuisances by using a Recordset insert or a parameterized query (via a QueryDef object).